# Expand element vertically to fill

Tags: javascript, html, css

Site: http://ace.brianhare.com/

How can I get it so the `section` and `aside` elements fill vertically and hide the yellow background?

Basically I don't want the yellow background to ever show.

It's OK to stretch everything vertically to do this, or if I have the choice, having the `div` with id `table` stretch and the `aside`.

Prefer css only but will accept javascript/Jquery solutions.

Comment: For me, it works by adding `height:100%` to *html*, *section*, and *aside*, and then `height: calc(100% - 50px);` to *#bounds*

Comment: Simple enough, please mark it as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this CSS-code:

```
html, body, aside, section {
  height:100%;
}

#bounds {
    height:-webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    height:-moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    height:-o-calc(100% - 50px);
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Because I am trying to get it to look relative on all browsers I ended up switching my footer from 50px to 7% and then just used 93% for `bounds` but good to know css can do calc!

Comment: Yes, calc is very handy sometimes. Only remember it's supported by around 82% of browsers, meaning that it isn't supported in some less 'popular' and older browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).